# Add extra column to an auto generated table of many-to-many relation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

EmployeeSupplier is auto generated table from many-to-many relation, I need to add an Active column to this table, this is what I did in Snaphot page:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity("EmployeeSupplier", b =>
            {
                b.Property<int>("EmployeesId")
                    .HasColumnType("int");

                b.Property<int>("SuppliersId")
                    .HasColumnType("int");

                b.Property<bool>("Active")
                    .HasColumnType("bit");

                b.HasKey("EmployeesId", "SuppliersId");

                b.HasIndex("SuppliersId");

                b.ToTable("EmployeeSupplier");
            });
```

But that is wrong.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem with helping of @IvanStoev like this:

- Delete the automatically generated table.
- Delete also `ICollection<Employee>` from `Supplier` and `ICollection<Supplier>` from `Employee`.
- Create a new class `EmployeeSupplier` that has `Employee` and `EmployeeId`, `Supplier` and `SupplierId` + **my extra fields**.
- Add `ICollection<EmployeeSupplier>` in both classes `Employee, Supplier`.
- Run the migration and updateDB and everything is perfect